# Two dimensional array sum in C#/Linq

Tags: linq, plinq

I have a two dimensional array of integers. I would like to write an optimized and fast code to sum all the columns of the two dimensional array.

Any thoughts how I might be able to do this using LINQ/PLINQ/TASK parallelization ?

Ex:

```
private int[,] m_indexes = new int[6,4]  { {367, 40, 74, 15},
                                           {535, 226, 74, 15}, 
                                           {368, 313, 74, 15},
                                           {197, 316, 74, 15}, 
                                           {27, 226, 74, 15},
                                           {194, 41, 74, 15} };
```

Comment: lots of thoughts, please be more specific

Comment: Actually..in real example... the size of the array is int[60,350]. I need to sum all the columns, then group few columns together to find the min and max in the total of those columns.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Parallel.For`?

Comment: Gabe - Not familiar will Parallel.For. I see Jason has given examples for Parallel.Foreach, and Linq. Going to benchmark and explore implementations further. Thanks all.

Comment: Instead of `Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 4), ...)` you could use `Parallel.For(0, 4, ...)`. This gives more opportunity for optimization because the number of columns are known at the outset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest parallel implementation:

```
 int[,] m_indexes = new int[6, 4]  { {367, 40, 74, 15},
                                     {535, 226, 74, 15}, 
                                     {368, 313, 74, 15},
                                     {197, 316, 74, 15}, 
                                     {27, 226, 74, 15},
                                     {194, 41, 74, 15} };
 var columns  = Enumerable.Range(0, 4);
 int[] sums = new int[4];
 Parallel.ForEach(columns, column => {
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         sum += m_indexes[i, column];
     }
            sums[column] = sum;
 });
```

This code can obviously be "generalized" (use `m_indexes.GetLength(0)` and `m_indexes.GetLength(1)`).

LINQ:

```
var sums = columns.Select(
    column => {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            sum += m_indexes[i, column];
         } return sum; 
    }
).ToArray();
```

Be sure to profile **on real-world data here** if you truly need to optimize for performance here.

Also, if you truly care about optimizing for performance, try to load up your array so that you summing across rows. You'll get better locality for cache performance that way.

Comment: (to the OP) But you should benchmark it before using it :-) For small arrays, the time spent synchronizing the threads is often > the time you gain.

Comment: `var columns  = Enumerable.Range(0, 4);` could be `var columns  = Enumerable.Range(0, m_indexes.GetLength(1));` for extensibility.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Going to explore the implementation and benchmark. Will implement accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chili Manku: Please read my last paragraph that I just edited in.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward LINQ way:

```
var columnSums = m_indexes.OfType<int>().Select((x,i) => new { x, col = i % m_indexes.GetLength(1) } )
    .GroupBy(x => x.col)
    .Select(x => new { Column = x.Key, Sum = x.Sum(g => g.x) });
```

It might not be worth it to parallelize. If you need to access the array by index, you spend some cycles on bounds checking, so, as always with performance, do measure it.

Comment: Meh. The JITter could very likely optimize the bounds checking away.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe without for's :

```
List<List<int>> m_indexes = new List<List<int>>()  { new List<int>(){367, 40, 74, 15},
new List<int>(){535, 226, 74, 15}, 
new List<int>(){368, 313, 74, 15},
new List<int>(){197, 316, 74, 15}, 
new List<int>(){27, 226, 74, 15},
new List<int>(){194, 41, 74, 15} };

var res = m_indexes.Select(x => x.Sum()).Sum();
```